# Asset Safety in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, iphone, app-store

Apparently I found the assets i.e. graphics, html etc I used in my compiled iPhone.app file.
This yields for a concern for its safety, anyone got something to say about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "...found the assets..."? Did you jailbreak your device, or were you just browsing the build-product on your computer?

Comment: just browsing the build-product

Comment: Your build-product is not in any way encrypted, so you can browse it at will. A skilled hacker will also be able to access your individual files on a jailbreaked device. If you have some security concerns for the content of individual files then you could look into various encryption schemes for these files.

Comment: That is surely going to be a processing overhead :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not safe at all, you can safely browse application directory using [iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/) on Mac or [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) on Windows ***even the device is not jailbroken***. So, leave it as is unless you want to waste some or more CPU time for decrypting those assets when your app starts, which can make it a little more safe**r**

Comment: It's been my experience that this generally is not a big deal. I hate having my custom textures and artwork out there as well, but would it ruin my business if someone stole them and used them in their app? No.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting data from an iPhone app is extremely simple - you do not even have to own an iPhone.

- Locate .ipa file on your file system
- Rename it to .zip
- Extract the content
- On mac: Use Display package content

It's all there - Images, files, sounds, ... no protection - nothing.

The only way to protect your content is to encrypt the data. Decoding it on the after/while loading.

This is not a 100% protection - simply because you have to add the key and the decoding algorithm to your application. Otherwise you would not be able to display the assets.

But: It should give script kiddies something to chew on - maybe they even search for easier prey.

If you encrypt your contents you should in my opinion also be free from filling out the encryption export statements - since only the decryption is available in your app and only for DRM / content protection.

I've decided to add an [content protection to TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/contentprotection) after some people in the cocos2d forums reported that some people created [exact clones of games](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/cloned-game-what-can-i-do/) - even using the original graphics and sounds. Apple seemed to have responded by removing the clone from appstore.